# css- background-color:#xxxxxx; not working

Tags: css, html, anchor, background-color

in my navigation bar i have this code.

```
<div id="aboutnav"><a class="hl" href="#"><h2>about\a</h2></a></div>
```

all the div does in the case is put the text in position and in the a.hl it's -

```
a.hl{

background-color:#000;
text-decoraction:none;
color:#fff;

}
```

the text is the right colour, it is in the correct position but there is no background colour.

Comment: doesnt a hex-color consist of 6 characters ?

Comment: this might help, a colour chart : http://www.somacon.com/p142.php

Comment: @Niklas: If you have pairs of the same character (`#ff00cc` for example), they can be simplified down to `#f0c` - it's correct syntax.

Comment: @Niklas No, Three digit hex colours are short forms `#000 === #000000`, `#F18 === #FF1188`

Comment: @Niklas.For colors yes,but hex numbers can be both longer and shorter than 6 characters.

Comment: @Niklas R no that assumption is wrong, that comment might give people wrong ideas... even more it is 'hex' or hexidecimal, it just denotes a number in 16 bits. it is an rgb code where every tow hexidecimal numbers are a color. in rgba a hex code would have 4/8 characters.

Comment: @Niklas No problem. SO is here for education and answers ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in HTML4/XHTML you can't nest hx elements into a! Try using this instead:

```
<div id="aboutnav"><h2><a class="hl" href="#">about\a</a></h2></div>
```

I think you would need to update your css in a similar way:

```
a.hl{
      display:block;
      background-color:#000;
      text-decoraction:none;
      color:#fff;    
}
```

Comment: More specifically it is illigal to wrap any block level element with an inline one (headers are block level, anchors are inline).

Answer (score 0):

Your style is probably being overridden by another style for `h2`. Try:

```
a.h1 h2{
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write the HTML like this

```
<div id="aboutnav">
    <h2>
        <a class="hl" href="#">about</a>
    </h2>
</div>
```

And then style it like so

```
#aboutnav h2 {
    background-color:#000;
}

#aboutnav h2 a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/rbxBL/

*Fyi... you had `text-decoration` misspelled.*

Also, you really don't need the class for the `a` when the HTML is done this way.